# $\int { \max { \left( 1,{ x }^{ 2 } \right) dx } }$

Tags: calculus

I am confused with this integral,can anybody help me,thanks beforehand
$$\int { \max { \left( 1,{ x }^{ 2 } \right) dx }  } $$

Comment: split up the range of integration into parts that are definitely one or the other of $1$ and $x^2$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**:

The function you are integrating is equal to:

$$f(x)=\begin{cases}x^2 & x \leq -1\\
1 & -1\leq x\leq 1\\
x^2 & 1\leq x\end{cases}$$

Answer (score 1):

So we begin by noting that $\max(1,x^2) = 1$, for all $|x|<1$, and $\max(1,x^{2})=x^{2}$, for all $|x|\geq 1$. So generally, if we integrate over a set $\Omega\subseteq \mathbb{R}$, then we have:

$$\int_{\Omega}\max(1,x^{2})\:\mathrm{d}x = \int_{\Omega \setminus [-1,1]}x^{2}\:\mathrm{d}x+\int_{\Omega \cap [-1,1]}\:\mathrm{d}x$$

Comment: I believe the OP is asking about a indefinite integral...

Comment: @5xum This function doesn't have a well-defined anti-derivative; I assumed that he would interested in the integral over some set, if you think I should delete my answer I will? :)

Comment: it is ok,Shaktal,thanks)